# JscrollPane not loading into div properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm having an issue with jscrollpane loading into a div using the following function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#shopping").click(function(event){
       $('#stage').hide();
      $('#stage').load('pages/shopping.html', {}, function() { $(this).fadeIn(800); });
```

The above code is on the index page and I'm calling up the "shopping page" as you can see above.
I have four other links that call up pages, one page has a slideshow and I managed to load that one into the div simply by eliminating the Jquery repository link, but this page doesn't want to know.

On the "shopping" page I have the following script, I've searched most of the web and also on here, without success, but nobody else's solutions have worked for me.
What am I doing wrong?:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="./css/jquery.jscrollpane.mod.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />


<script>

$(function()
{
$('.horizontal-only').jScrollPane(
{
    showArrows: true,
    arrowScrollOnHover: true,
    horizontalArrowPositions: 'split',
    hijackInternalLinks: false
}
);

  });
```

Comment: The page loads in the div when the above function is removed, obviously removing the functionality of jscrollpane at the same time, I don't know if there is an issue there?

Comment: What's the "autoReinitialise: true" doing there in the first snippet? It's not in an object definition.

Comment: It's just something I tried but forgot to ommit

Comment: really no one has any pointers on this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok...
After some digging and trial and error, I've found the solution to my problem, hunting on the web and stack, I found something that worked and I thought for all those that are complete noobs, like me, in javascript and Jquery I'd post my findings.

Current call up on index page:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#shopping").click(function(event){
       $('#stage').hide();
      $('#stage').load('pages/shopping.html', {}, function() { $(this).fadeIn(800); });
```

I added the following to my index page (this is the page that is calling up the other pages)
to the link of a specific page add:

```
 $.ajaxSetup({async:false});
```

then add the jScrollPane function after your call up e.g:

```
 $('#stage').jScrollPane(
{
    showArrows: true,
    arrowScrollOnHover: true,
    horizontalArrowPositions: 'split',
    hijackInternalLinks: false
}
);
```

So altogether it looks like this:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#shopping").click(function(event){
       $('#stage').hide();
 //--added the async code here--//
       $.ajaxSetup({async:false});
      $('#stage').load('pages/shopping.html', {}, function() { $(this).fadeIn(800); });
 //--moved the jscrollPane from the page I was calling to the index page code here--//  
      $('#stage').jScrollPane(
{
    showArrows: true,
    arrowScrollOnHover: true,
    horizontalArrowPositions: 'split',
    hijackInternalLinks: false
}
);
```

This seems to be working for me at the moment, now I just need to re-edit some css and it's good to go.

Comment: Update, for some reason it only loads when clicked on once if the link is clicked again it doesn't load the jscrollpane script. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

I've found another workaround:

I've added the following code to the index.html:

```
$(function()
{
var api = $('.horizontal-only').jScrollPane(

{
    showArrows: true,
    arrowScrollOnHover: true,
    horizontalArrowPositions: 'split',
    hijackInternalLinks: false
}
).data('jsp');

$('#shopping').bind(
    'click',
    function()
    {
        api.getContentPane().load(
            'pages/shopping.html',
            function()
            {
                api.reinitialise();
            }
        );
        return false;
    }
);
});
```

I also made the jsp load in a separate div layer, as it was causing some styling conflicts and i can't determine where the issue is but this works.

What I also had to do is hide the new div layer from the other calls
so basically:

```
$(#scroller).hide();
```

Thanks, I'm sure this isn't the best way, but as i've only had one reply on this issue, which was a question, think I've done rather well for a noob.